# I want to find those profile who have more posts by ascending order in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my Profile schema

```
const profileSchema = new Schema({
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User',
        required:true
    },
    posts:[
        {
            type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'Post'
        }
    ],
    
})
```

I want to find those profile who have more post.
i tired many ways but couldnt. please help me to find out this query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for simplicity a set of two documents like these

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6166ecc8d82d2c783d8458b9"),
    "user" : "Joe Sat",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "post" : "my post"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6166ecd8d82d2c783d846d64"),
    "user" : "Steve Iav",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "4",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5",
            "post" : "my post"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "6",
            "post" : "my post"
        }
    ]
}
```

then for getting list of users ordered by posts number, you can use a query like this. Based on what you want to get in terms of data, you can remove or add fields in the project pipeline.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([ 
      {$project: { user : "$user", 
                   posts  : "$posts", postsNr: {$size:"$posts"}}},
      {$sort : {postsNr: -1}}
 ])
```